# Consistently compiling C code with -fPIC for a rust ffi crate

Tags: python, c, gcc, rust, ffi

My rust project uses a FFI to the C lib SuperLU, which is called [superlu-sys](https://github.com/stainless-steel/superlu-sys). My rust code produces Python bindings with PyO3. As soon as the python bindings have a function calling SuperLU I get the following linker error on building:

```
relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

This is strange as -fPIC is enforced by build.rs of superlu-sys:

```
run!(cmd!("make")
    .current_dir(&source.join("SRC"))
    .arg("NOOPTS=-O0 -fPIC -w")
    .arg("CFLAGS=-O3 -DNDEBUG -DPRNTlevel=0 -fPIC -w")
    .arg("DZAUX=")
    .arg("SCAUX=")
    .arg(&format!("SuperLUroot={}", source.display()))
    .arg(&format!(
        "SUPERLULIB={}",
        lib.join("libsuperlu.a").display()
    )));
```

Here is the full [build.rs](https://github.com/stainless-steel/superlu-sys/blob/master/build.rs).

On producing a minimum example I have found that it works as long as the PyO3 bindings are in the same crate in which SuperLu is built. I am under the impression that the adherence to the flags from build.rs is only given if it it the root of the crate tree.

How can I modify build.rs to get consistent enforcement of -fPIC?

This is a minimum example causing the issue:
lib.rs:

```
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use std::os::raw::c_int;
use superlu_sys;

#[pyclass]
pub struct Object {}

#[pymethods]
impl Object {
    pub fn test(&self) -> i32 {
        unsafe {
            *superlu_sys::intMalloc(1 as c_int)
        }
    }
}

#[allow(unused)]
#[pymodule]
fn bind_superlu(py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<Object>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "bind_superlu"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "ress"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
superlu-sys = "0.3.4"
pyo3 = {version = "0.18.1", features = ["auto-initialize"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the buid.rs script to using the cmake rust crate instead of invoking make as a subprocess.